# Is it safe to create a Bitcoin account for another party? Is this a scam?

Tags: security, fraud

A guy I have been talking to says he is having trouble accessing his account and asked me to make a wallet in blockchain and then wants my login, password, and wallet id so he can use it in another country. I have $0.00 in my wallet. Is this safe to do? I’m trying to figure out if this is a scam and if so how ? I also have no intentions of buying any bitcoin for myself now or in the future

Answer (score 3):

This is unsafe and definitely a scam.

One common way it's done is as follows.  Using your login and password, the guy will secretly retrieve the recovery phrase for the wallet.  He will then let you change the password.  Then, he will make up some story to convince you to acquire some Bitcoins and put them in the wallet (or maybe he'll just wait until you decide to do so of your own accord).  You will think this is safe because he doesn't know the new password.  However, using the recovery phrase, he will be able to take all the coins from the wallet, even without the password.

If he really just wanted access to a Blockchain wallet, there would be nothing to stop him from just making one for himself.

Answer (score 0):

Known scam. There are different scenarious but the main point is to lower your attention with ‘sounds legit’ agenda. Read about nigerian prince ;)

Comment: I don't understand the connection between "sounds legit" and "nigerian prince", as these both things seem to be the opposite of each other.

Answer (score -1):

he maybe does not harm you with that, but others for sure. why whould someoone nbeed a Wallet not connected to him.
It will be your Door the Police kicks in.